# Java : threaded serial port read with Java.util.concurrent thread access

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, serial-port

I'm trying to write a Java serial device driver and want to use the (new to me) `java.util.concurrent` package.  I have one method which sends a packet then waits for an ACK.  I plan to have char. reception run in a different thread.  If the receive thread gets an ACK it should notify the thread with the send packet function.  The receive thread implements a state machine and should notify any listeners of decoded packets.

I think I know how to do this using direct Threads, `wait`, `notify` etc., but am not sure how to do this with the new concurrent package.  Would be very grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`CyclicBarrier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). Here's a cite of relevance from its Javadoc:

> A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.

So, you need to create a `CyclicBarrier` for a number of `2` parties and let the receiver thread invoke `await()` after ACK and let the sender thread invoke `await()` before doing the SEND.

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to get you started.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q3379797;

import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
        Receiver receiver = new Receiver(barrier);
        Sender sender = new Sender(barrier);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executor.submit(receiver);
        executor.submit(sender);
    }

}

class Receiver implements Runnable {

    private CyclicBarrier barrier;

    public Receiver(CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        this.barrier = barrier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Wait for ACK (the sleep just simulates that).
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("ACK");

                // Then notify.
                barrier.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Sender implements Runnable {

    private CyclicBarrier barrier;

    public Sender(CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        this.barrier = barrier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Wait for notify.
                barrier.await();

                // Now do SEND.
                System.out.println("SEND");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see the following in the stdout:

```
(2 seconds)
ACK
SEND
(2 seconds)
ACK
SEND
(2 seconds)
ACK
SEND
```